# Django form for dynamic hidden input fields

Tags: django, forms, validation

I have two models, Post and Attachment. Attachment has a foreign key to Post.

I have a PostCreateView with PostForm.

While writing a post, you may upload images using jquery-fileupload (AJAX). If files are uploaded the following lines are appended to `<form>`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="attachments" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="attachments" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="attachments" value="3" />
```

The values(1, 2 and 3) are PK for Attachment model in order to make a relationship between Post and Attachment when I save a post.

I was able to get a list in PostCreateView:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    attachments = self.request.POST.getlist('attachments')
```

However, I'd like to declare the form field in PostForm for the following validations:

- PKs must be integers.
- Attachment's foreign key must be null with those PKs.
- The number of PKs must be limited (5 or 10).

A post may have NO attachment, so the attachment hidden input tag does not exist at first. That's why it could be hard to have a form field. These are appended by AJAX/jQuery. If it is diffcult, I'd like to know the best practice which method shoud be overridden in CreateView.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I answer by myself.

1. `PostForm` doesn't have a hidden field for PKs for `Attachment`.
2. `PostAttachmentForm` inherits `PostForm`, and `clean_attachment()` checks if list items are all integers.

   ```
   class PostAttachmentForm(PostForm):
       attachments = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

       def clean_attachments(self):
           data = self.data.getlist('attachments')

           if not data and not all(isinstance(item, int) for item in data):
               raise forms.ValidationError("PK must be integers.")

           return data
   ```
3. `PostCreateView` has `get_form_class` instead of `form_class` field.

   ```
   def get_form_class(self):
       if self.request.method == 'POST':
           # NOTE: Hidden fields must be validated.
           return PostAttachmentForm
       else:
           # NOTE: Hidden fields are not prepopulated but appended to form by AJAX.
           return PostForm
   ```
4. `form_valid()` for relatioinship and validation between Post and Attachment

   ```
   def form_valid(self, form):
       response = super().form_valid(form)

       # TODO: limit number

       # Attachments are not related to any post yet.
       attachments = Attachment.objects.filter(
           pk__in=form.cleaned_data['attachments'],
           post__isnull=True,
       )
       self.object.attachments.set(attachments)

       return response
   ```

I would really appreciate if you have a better way.